# I encountered a bug leading to Preview crash

Tags: swift, swiftui

[In this image I print some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMBnN.png)
[Preview crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NSk1.png)

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegisterView: View {
    
    var UserInfo: [String: Student] = [:]
    
    enum myAlert {
        case success
        case fail_nil
        case fail_codenil
        case fail_codeless
        case fail_hadregi
    }
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertType: myAlert? = nil
    @State private var stuid = ""
    @State private var stuname = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var showingLoginScreen = false
    @State private var HadRegi = false
    @State private var Vertify = false
    @State private var Regisuccess = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "road.lanes.curved.right")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("注册")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                
                TextField("请输入您的学号", text: $stuid)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .border(.black, width: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                TextField("请输入您的姓名", text: $stuname)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .border(.black, width: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                SecureField("请设置您的密码", text: $password)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .border(.black, width: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                    Button("注册") {
                        print(stuid)
                        print(stuname)
                        print(password)
                        showAlert.toggle()
                        authenticateUser(stuname: stuname, stuid: stuid)
                    }
                    .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                        getAlert()
                    })
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $Regisuccess) {
                    WelcomeView()
                }
            }
        }
    
    func authenticateUser(stuname: String, stuid: String) {
        
        if stuid == "" || stuname == "" {
            alertType = .fail_nil
        } else if password == "" {
            alertType = .fail_codenil
        } else { //first else
            
            if let stu = AccessibleGroup[stuid] {
                if stu.name == stuname {
                    Vertify = true
                }
            }
            
            if let stu = UserInfo[stuid] {
                if stu.name == stuname {
                    HadRegi = true
                }
            }
            Vertify = true
            
            if Vertify {
                if password.count < 8 {
                    alertType = .fail_codeless
                } else if HadRegi {
                    alertType = .fail_hadregi
                    HadRegi = false
                }
                else {//second else
                    
                    alertType = .success
//                    let newUser = User.init(stuName: stuname, stuId: stuid, UserName: "", sex: AccessibleGroup[stuid]!.sex, birthday: AccessibleGroup[stuid]!.birthday, sign_major: AccessibleGroup[stuid]!.major, sign_hobbies: [], sign_mbti: "", sign_major_pre: [], sign_others: [], code: password, new: true, single: nil, inPushToOthers: false, inOthersPushMe: false, age: AccessibleGroup[stuid]!.age)
                    Regisuccess = true
                    
                }//second else
            }
            
        } //first else
    }
    
    func getAlert() -> Alert {
        switch alertType {
        case .success:
            return Alert(title: Text("注册成功"))
        case .fail_nil:
            return Alert(title: Text("请输入您的姓名学号"))
        case .fail_codenil:
            return Alert(title: Text("请输入您的密码"))
        case .fail_codeless:
            return Alert(title: Text("密码不足八位"))
        case .fail_hadregi:
            return Alert(title: Text("该账号已被注册"))
        default:
            return Alert(title: Text("ERROR"))
        }
    }
    
}
    


#Preview {
    RegisterView()
}
```

I want to implement a Register function in this block. But when I handle my data, my Preview crashed.

Here are my User , Student and AcccessibleGroup definition

```
class User {
    
    
    var stuName: String
    var stuId: String
    var UserName: String
    var sex: Bool // 0 is man ; 1 is woman
    var birthday: String
    var code: String
    var new: Bool
    var age: Int
    var sign_major: String?
    var sign_major_pre: Array<String>
    var sign_hobbies: Array<String>
    var sign_mbti: String?
    var sign_others: Array<String>
    var single: Bool?
    var inPushToOthers: Bool
    var inOthersPushMe: Bool
    
    init(stuName: String, stuId: String, UserName: String, sex: Bool, birthday: String, sign_major: String?, sign_hobbies: Array<String>, sign_mbti: String?, sign_major_pre: Array<String>, sign_others: Array<String>, code: String, new: Bool, single: Bool?, inPushToOthers: Bool, inOthersPushMe: Bool, age: Int) {
        self.stuName = stuName
        self.stuId = stuId
        self.UserName = UserName
        self.sex = sex
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.sign_major = sign_major
        self.sign_major_pre = sign_major_pre
        self.sign_hobbies = sign_hobbies
        self.sign_mbti = sign_mbti
        self.sign_others = sign_others
        self.code = code
        self.new = new
        self.single = single
        self.inOthersPushMe = inOthersPushMe
        self.inPushToOthers = inPushToOthers
        self.age = age
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Student: Hashable, Codable{
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var sex: Bool
    var major: String
    var age: Int
    var birthday: String
}
```

```
import Foundation

var AccessibleGroup: [String: Student] = load("AccessibleData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't fine \(filename) in main bundle")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

I tried to delete some code to locate the position of error.And I find my error is in

```
if let stu = AccessibleGroup[stuid] {
                if stu.name == stuname {
                    Vertify = true
                }
            }
            
            if let stu = UserInfo[stuid] {
                if stu.name == stuname {
                    HadRegi = true
                }
            }
```

and

```
if let astu = AccessibleGroup[stuid] {
                        print(astu)
                        let newUser = User.init(stuName: stuname, stuId: stuid, UserName: "1", sex: astu.sex, birthday: astu.birthday, sign_major: astu.major, sign_hobbies: [], sign_mbti: "1", sign_major_pre: [], sign_others: [],password: password, new: true, single: true, inPushToOthers: false, inOthersPushMe: false, age: astu.age)
                    }
```

In fact when I only left

```
if let stu = AccessibleGroup[stuid] {
                if stu.name == stuname {
                    Vertify = true
                }
            }
```

It crash too! But I think it's safe.

I don't know why.Any help will be appreciated.

Update：
I just modified the dictionary in the JSON file to have a fixed value while debugging, and made sure that my input exists in the dictionary. However, it still crashed.

UPdate:
The error is in newUser init(), and I modify my code as matt's suggestion, but Preview still crash.

UPdate：
Here is my json:

```
{
    "22371187":{

        "name":     "周舟舟",
        "id":       "22371187",
        "sex":      "true",
        "birthday": "2003-09-29",
        "age":      "20",
        "major":    "计算机"

    },

    "1":{
        
        "name":     "zzh",
        "id":       "1",
        "sex":      "true",
        "birthday": "2003-09-29",
        "age":      "20",
        "major":    "宇航学"

    },

    "22371188":{
        
        "name":     "黄小姐",
        "id":       "22371188",
        "sex":      "false",
        "birthday": "2004-09-24",
        "age":      "19",
        "major":    "经济学"

    },

    "22371189":{
        
        "name":     "张三",
        "id":       "22371189",
        "sex":      "true",
        "birthday": "2003-07-19",
        "age":      "20",
        "major":    "软件工程"

    },

    "22371190":{
        
        "name":     "李四",
        "id":       "22371190",
        "sex":      "false",
        "birthday": "2003-08-23",
        "age":      "20",
        "major":    "数学"

    },

    "22371191":{
        
        "name":     "王五",
        "id":       "22371191",
        "sex":      "true",
        "birthday": "2004-09-29",
        "age":      "19",
        "major":    "物理"

    }
}
```

Comment: Any time you say `!`, that _means_ "crash". You are asking to crash and you are crashing. If you don't want that to happen, don't do that; unwrap Optionals _safely_.

Comment: Also, I think you have not given enough information; what is this AccessibleGroup that keeps appearing in your code? I don't see a definition for that.

Comment: I am sorry for information lack. I have add it in my question.

Comment: Like @matt suggested, you're probably unwrapping an Optional that doesn't exist in the JSON you've decoded. But, since we don't have the JSON, we have no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: But I use ***if let*** I think it's safe.By the way I just modified the dictionary in the JSON file to have a fixed value while debugging, and made sure that my input exists in the dictionary. However, it still crashed.

Comment: Run it in a real project so you can see what the crash really is

Comment: Not sure but you toggle the alert before setting the alert type in authenticateUser. You should try to toggle showAlert after you set  the alert type.

Comment: One of my bug is in SwiftData. Another is in my Json.I solved SwiftData problem and still checking my Json.Thank for your help and look forward to more help.